# Exception handling in FTP task of SSIS

Tags: file, ssis, ftp, task, delete-file

I have a FTP task in my SSIS package which deletes files from FTP location. 
But the issue is that if the file(s) or directory is not available on the server, the task gets failed.

Is there any way that I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. The task should fail and then you should do something detecting the failure. This logic can be executed on the task failure event or by drawing the red arrow to some error handling logic from the FTP task.

Comment: I am now using the blue arrow to move to next task, by doing so even if the task fails, it moves to next task, but now the issue, is if the task fails due to some other reason i.e. of not finding the specified file/folder, the task will still move on. Any way I can come to know that what was the cause of failure.

Comment: You can write a script for the event handler to examine the error and take corrective measures accordingly, I guess...